# android - how to send data from service to fragment "every second"?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, fragment, broadcast

I have a media player service, and I need the fragment UI to be updated or in sync with the service data.
Currently I am using a Broadcast to send and receive the data. But my question is, is there a better way to do this in android?

In Service:

```
private void startBroadcast() {
    if(broadcastThread!= null && !broadcastThread.isInterrupted())
        broadcastThread.interrupt();
    broadcastThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(!isInterrupted()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FILTER);
                    intent.putextra("foo",1);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    broadcastThread.start();
}
```

In Fragment:

```
private BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int foo= intent.getIntExtra("foo", 0);
        // bla bla
    }
};
.
.
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).registerReceiver(serviceReceiver ,FILTER);
}
```

Comment: use [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bind Service to connect service to your activity 
and after that update all of your fragment with that

```
bindService(oIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = 
    new ServiceConnection(){
        public void onServiceConnected(
            ComponentName cName, IBinder service){
                MyBinder binder = (MyService.MyBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService(); 
                // Get a reference to the Bound Service object.
                mServiceBound = true;
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName cName){
        mServiceBound= false;
    }
};
```

and after you want change your activity you should unbind connection

```
if (mServiceBound){
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mServiceBound = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with MediaPlayer, I had to update UI component in every seconds, too.
I used Runnable + Handler combo, like this:

```
//...
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mSeekBarUpdater
//...

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
 //...
    int result;
      // ...
    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        // Start playing and set isPlaying to true. This attribute is required on rotating screen
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
        /**
         * Preparing Handler object and a Runnable in order to
         * update SeekBar status
         */
        if (mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler();
        }
        if (mSeekBarUpdater == null) {
            mSeekBarUpdater = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                
                    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mHandler != null) {
                        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            // Refreshing SeekBar position
                            mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();                              
                            mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
// .. put your code here in order to refresh your UI components
                        }
                        // Refreshing on every second
                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(mSeekBarUpdater);
    }
}
```